# Include a node module through express.static

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have a node server running on localhost:3002. This server is serving some static html and plain JavaScript content. I am accessing this content through an iFrame on a Vue.js application.

My question is when I use 
`app.use(express.static('./game'));` Can I include a node module along with this action?

My reasoning for this is, within one of the plain JavaScript files of the static content, I want to use `require()` and obviously this does not work.

I know that I could access the module I want directly from the plain JavaScript file using a `<script>` tag, but I don't really want to send this to the client side directly.

Is it possible to have something that looks like this? `app.use(express.static('./game'), express.static('/node_modules/jsonwebtoken');` as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but it is not highly recommended. You could solve it as follows.

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './game')))
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/jsonwebtoken')))
```

The ideal would be to implement different logic for each area, back-end ~ front-end. This in the given case that you are developing a client-side.

Now if you are developing a server-side, the logic already changes, since the server directly renders the view internally.

Another important point to highlight is that depending on both the back-end and the front-end of the same resource, it can lead to breaking the code, on one side or the other. For a simple update of said resource.

I hope that it clarifies you to the doubt. Some doubt comment it.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Front end and back end would never be accessing the resources concurrently. Essentially I have a token stored as a cookie and I want to decode a property from the cookie which goes in as part of a request body to my API to retrieve a resource from my DB. This is all done within the iFrame and no interaction takes place in the Vue app during this time

Comment: Ok, I think I understood, do you want to extract a data from the token that you encrypted on the server on the client side?

Comment: Exactly yeah. So I would get the cookie and then decode it so I can grab the email from the token and use that as a body param for my API

Comment: Well it is not a good idea that the token is decoded on the client side, it would lose all its security.

In fact, the token itself is the identifier of the user.

Comment: The methodology will be used json web token, it is based on sending the credentials necessary to authenticate the user to the back-end, and later the back-end returns an authentication token, all this will be done to avoid that the user does not have to constantly send new credentials for each request.